# expect script how to check for conditions

Tags: expect

Is there a way to check each expect condition with a loop and have if statements?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet 10.10.10.10
set timeout 200000000
expect "login"
send "user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
send "./run/this.sh\r"
/* 
Here is where I'm confused 
*/

if[ "expect" = "close" ] 
then
    send "exit\r"
elif[ "expect" = "end" ] 
    send "exit\r"
fi
```

Comment: Were you able to use my below logic?

Comment: Note, use `set timeout -1` to disable the timeout. Unless you specifically want to wait for up to 2314.8 days for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if-elsif` conditional in `expect` is something like below for your case. You are literally doing the same action for both the cases, but here is how it is done.

```
expect {
  "close" {
    send "exit\r"
  }
  "end" {
    send "exit\r"
  }
}
```